# Prime index subgroup of $\langle Q^{i}(\mathbb Z^{2}) \mid i \in \mathbb Z \rangle$ that is invariant under matrix $Q$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, galois-theory

Let $Q $ be a matrix in $ \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q}) $ and consider the group
$G = \langle Q^{i}(\mathbb Z^{2}) \mid i \in \mathbb Z \rangle :=  \langle Q^{i}(v) \mid i \in \mathbb Z, v \in \mathbb Z^{2}  \rangle$ under vector addition.

**Question:** What are the prime index subgroups $H$ of $\langle Q^{i}(\mathbb Z^{2}) \mid i \in \mathbb Z \rangle$  such that for all $v \in H$, we have $Q(v) \in H$?

I am interested in the case when both $Q$ and $Q^{-1}$ have non-integral coefficients in their characteristic polynomial ([Here are some equivalent conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4632071/976076)).

**"Easy" case**: When $Q$ (or $Q^{-1}$) is an integer matrix
we can start with a subgroup $ H' $ of $\mathbb Z^2$ that has finite index $p$ and is invariant under $Q$, then $H=\langle Q^{i}( H') \mid i \in \mathbb Z \rangle$ would be a subgroup of $ G$ which has finite index $p$ and is invariant under $Q$.

One of the reasons we can do this is because when $Q$ is an integer matrix, we have $\langle Q^{i}(v)\mid i\in\mathbb Z,v\in\mathbb Z^{2}\rangle = \langle Q^{-i}(v)\mid i\in\mathbb N,v\in\mathbb Z^{2}\rangle$. However, it is quite difficult to [show that this holds for the general rational matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/q/454636/479955).

**Where I get this question from:** I am trying to find all the finite index subgroups of $G$ that are invariant under $Q$. Given a prime $p$ that is coprime to all the denominators of the entries in $Q$ and $Q^{-1}$, we know that $ \langle Q^{i}(p\mathbb Z^{2}) \mid i \in \mathbb Z \rangle$ would have finite index $p^2$ and is invariant under $Q$, I was wondering if there are any other finite index invariant subgroup.

Thank you for reading. Any ideas for constructing such a subgroup would be really appreciated.

Comment: Interesting. I don't have any intuition about this, but to build it from the ground up I am tempted to look at what happens in cases like
$$Q=\pmatrix{2&0\cr0&1/3\cr}$$ and
$$Q=\pmatrix{0&2\cr 1/3&0\cr}.$$
I don't expect to learn everything from such examples, but may be something. A possible problem may be that Smith normal forms of (suitably scaled) powers of $Q$ don't line up nicely. Scratching my head. Gotta go, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen. Could you give me a hint of how Smith normal form could help? The span of the column space will change after performing elementary row operations. (Maybe you mean Reduced Column echelon form?)

Comment: May be there is nothing to it? Smith normal form may help for a single matrix in the sense that if $PAQ=D$ with $P,Q$ invertible, then $AQ(\Bbb{Z}^2)=A(\Bbb{Z}^2)$, so
$A(\Bbb{Z}^2)=P^{-1}D(\Bbb{Z}^2)$. Yes, the application of $P^{-1}$ will change the group. And you also have the powers $A^i$ to deal with.

Comment: Sorry, you had $Q$ in place of $A$ everywhere. I was too used to using $Q$ as the column operation factor in SNF :-9